# How to optimize build times for unit test target

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, tdd, compile-time

We have an 4 years old iOS app with partly old codebase. We are using the VIPER architecture, Quick and Nimble and want to use TDD (test driven development) for our new module (feature).

For TDD you have to build the test-target a lot. But our unit test build needs a lot of time, so in fact TDD would make no sense because it would take too long time. Seems like incremental builds are not working (old Xcode problem, I think)

We have tried to have a separate module test target without an host-application. That work, but the downside is, that we have to add all dependencies to that target if we reference that in e.g. our system under test.

Is there a better way to achieve our goal for faster unit-tests compile time so that we can use TDD?

Comment: As the new feature is a different module, does having tests to that specific module as a different module also causes the same issue as above?

Comment: Does your project have custom build phases? For example, to run SwiftFormat.